# Obtain a Count of all the combinations created in a column when grouping by another column in df with different length combinations in R

Tags: r

Sample data frame

```
Guest <- c("ann","ann","beth","beth","bill","bill","bob","bob","bob","fred","fred","ginger","ginger")
State <- c("TX","IA","IA","MA","AL","TX","TX","AL","MA","MA","IA","TX","AL")
df <- data.frame(Guest,State)
```

Desired output

[image]

I have tried about a dozen different ideas but not getting close.  Closest was setting up a crosstab but didn't know how to get counts from that.  Long/wide got me nowhere.  etc.  Too new still to think out of the box I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach. You can arrange your values and then use `group_by()` and `summarise()` to reach a structure similar to those expected:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>%
  arrange(Guest,State) %>%
  group_by(Guest) %>%
  summarise(Chain=paste0(State,collapse = '-')) %>%
  group_by(Chain,.drop = T) %>%
  summarise(N=n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Chain        N
  <chr>    <int>
1 AL-MA-TX     1
2 AL-TX        2
3 IA-MA        2
4 IA-TX        1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I had to remove duplication between the two involved values to get the output exactly as needed.  Thank You

Comment: @Bruce Fantastic! Always a pleasure helping :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` with `aggregate` and `table`

```
table(aggregate(State~ Guest, df[do.call(order, df),], paste, collapse='-')$State)
```

-output

```
#  AL-MA-TX    AL-TX    IA-MA    IA-TX 
#     1        2        2        1
```